# Translating C# code to VB.net

Tags: c#, vb.net

I'm trying to translate this C# code to VB.net

```
var messages = animalmgr.ReadFile(thefilename); 
//Getting method from manager
if (messages != null)
{
    messages.ToList().ForEach(msg => Resultlst.Items.Add(msg));
}
```

I tried it like this:

```vb
Dim message = animalmgr.ReadFile(thefilename)
If (Not (message) Is Nothing) Then
    'I don't know how the code below are supposed to be
    message.ToList.ForEach(() => {  }, Resultlst.Items.Add(msg))
End If
```

I would appreciate if anyone could help me out. Thanks.

Comment: Also use `If message IsNot Nothing Then`.

Comment: Telerik provides a free [C# -> VB converter online](http://converter.telerik.com/). It's a pretty useful tool.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

VB lambda functions are a bit different.  Here is how it looks in VB.Net:

```
message.ToList().ForEach(Sub(msg) Resultlst.Items.Add(msg))
```

Comment: I got error "Nested sub does not have a signature that is compatible with delegate"

Comment: Do we know from the question that `msg` is a `String`?  Maybe just remove the `As String` part and hope `Option Infer On`?

Comment: Fixed. Removed type of msg parameter.